# Resharper Generate from usage, setting to not move to implementation?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

When using generate from usage of resharper, immediately after accepting the option to generate property/method/type. The caret is moved to implementation point.

Is there a setting to remain where the usage is without moving to implementation?

Comment: It would be nice, if we have the option to generate multiple members in one click - for example select some code lines and generate all memebrs within selection.

Comment: @Mic yes, I think o was using a such a feature in Delphi back in 2002, still waiting for it in vs

Comment: maybe write custom resharper extension :)